# Problems obtaining number of Rows of a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've been working in a mixture of a project that contains Javascript and ASP.net.

I'm trying to retrieve the number of columns of a dynamic table which will fill every time all the input fields from one row is full.

The script that creates the rows is the following :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           var table = $('#tablaSKU');
           rowCount = 1;

function appendRow() {
               var content = table.data('row-prototype').replace(/__id__/g, rowCount);

               table.find('tbody').append(content);
                  ++rowCount;
               document.getElementById('rowCounter').innerHTML = rowCount - 1;
           }

           $(function () {
               appendRow(); // Append the first row on page load

               $('div#myform').on('change', function () {
                   var inputs = $(this).find(':input,select'),
        valid = true;
                   $.each(inputs, function () {
                       if ($(this).val() == '') {
                           valid = false;
                       }
                   });

                   if ((valid) && rowCount < 11) {
                       appendRow();

                   }
                   if ((valid) && rowCount >= 11) {
                       window.alert("Ha alcanzado el número máximo de SKUs(10)");
                   }
               });
           });
</script>
```

As you can see in the end of the function `appendRow()` I've tried to bind the value `RowCount` to a hidden label `rowCounter`, but later on I can't access to that value from the code behind.

I've also tried to access the value by setting the `<table>` tag `runat="server"`, but the following code

```
Contador = tablaSKU.Rows.Count
```

Returns a static value of the table of 1, no matter when I test and add 5 rows later, the value remains also as 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you can get the row count by `$('#tablaSKU td').length`

Comment: Hello @RRR. I know how to get the number of columns I just don't know how to transfer that number to the code behind, tried to access the table from code behind and also tried to put it in a label.

Comment: not sure by i think you need to use AJAX to achieve it

Comment: or else try this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-JavaScript-variable-value-to-Server-Side-Code-Behind-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Hello once again @RRR,

the snippet worked really well!

Thank you!